# Cryptographic Hash Function

Tags: cryptography

I have an exam tomorrow on cryptography and came across an old exam question on hash functions and finding out the probability of collision of two hash values being the same, but I don't know how to calculate it. The question is:

If the hash value is a 20 bit output and allowable inputs must not exceed 2^64 bits, what is the probability of two randomly chosen values yielding a collision?

Was hoping someone could provide a solution.
Thanks.

Comment: http://crypto.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Should be 1 / (2 ^ 20). (It should be independent of the length of the Input if you consider 2 randomly choosen inputs (and not ALL possible inputs), given the hash function is proper.) So I guess the additional Information about the length of the Input is just to make you crazy.

Comment: If the allowable input length was shorter than 20 bits, then that would reduce the likelihood of a collision.

Comment: @NickJohnson Nope, not if you just choose two non-identical values from it. Likelihood would be exactly as large (unless you precalculated the output values of course), assuming that the output is indistinguishable from random for any input value.